# How to disable fullscreen on electron window (linux)

Tags: electron

These are the only four attributes mentioned in docs.

(1) `minimizable`

(2) `maximizable`

(3) `fullscreen`

(4) `fullscreenable`

While former two specify that these aren't implemented on Linux, the latter two are for mac only.

So, how do I prevent user from making the window occupy full screen on Linux? And what's the point of having max height and max width properties then (I can't drag and resize beyond those but I can still maximize the window)?

Code:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow,Menu } = require('electron');
const path = require('path');

require('electron-reload')(__dirname, {
  electron: path.join(__dirname,'..', 'node_modules', '.bin', 'electron')
});

// Handle creating/removing shortcuts on Windows when installing/uninstalling.
if (require('electron-squirrel-startup')) { // eslint-disable-line global-require
  app.quit();
}


let mainWindow;

const createWindow = () => {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 550,
    height: 500,
    skipTaskbar: true,
    maxWidth:1000,
    maxHeight:800,
    show:false,
    fullscreenable:false,
    fullscreen: false,
    maximizable: false
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL({url});

  mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    mainWindow.show()
  })


  mainWindow.on('closed', () => {
    mainWindow = null;
  });
};

app.on('ready', createWindow);

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (mainWindow === null) {
    createWindow();
  }
});
```

Comment: Set `fullscreenable` as `false`. You are misinterpreting the described "specific behavior for MacOS" as "MacOS feature only". `fullscreenable` is cross-platform supported.

Comment: @Seblor I set all four to false. still maximizable

Comment: That's weird. Can you include your code in your question ?

Comment: @Seblor Added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, as said in the docs, [maximizable has not been implemented in Linux](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winmaximizable).

I have not found a "proper" solution, but a work-around.

You should be able to listen to the `maximize` event, and then call the `unmaximize` method (I don't see any warning about this event or method about Linux so they should be available). So essentially you would "cancel" the maximizing.

```
mainWindow.on('maximize', () => {
  mainWindow.unmaximize()
});
```

Comment: Yea, kinda works, but I would like to know if a proper way exists. thanks for the suggestion though :). I liked how the window dances to max and back to normal, fun to watch XD

Answer (score 0):

set `resizable` key to false:

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
     resizable: false
});
```

This should disable the fullscreen button on the m